# UICollectionView does not produce cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to create a collection view with custom layout, which allows cells to span multiple lines as shown here:

http://stripysock.com.au/blog/2013/2/21/creating-a-custom-collection-view-layout

Also an author provided us with the way to position our cells and calculating content size.
I've found another tut http://damir.me/implementing-uicollectionview-layout
with the source code and it is almost what i need.The problem is that in this project cells span only columns, so the height of cells is fixed, consequently simpler logic with independent columns for each row. I didn't see any way on how to change second tut to suit my needs and decided to synthesize them.I borrowed implementation for cells,collection view controller and app delegate from second tut and custom layout from first.

The Problem: it didn't work,collection view is there but cells aren't. I've put a bunch of NSLog's in my code and in second tut and figured out that my code doesn't call initWithFrame method of collection view cell although it's pretty same.

Question:I am struggling with this for a week and can't understand what I am missing.Can somebody suggest something?

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "CollectionViewController.h"
#import "CollectionViewLayout.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //именно здесь мы создаем наш collection view
    CollectionViewLayout *collectionViewLayout = [[CollectionViewLayout alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"a layout initialized");

    CollectionViewController *collectionViewController = [[CollectionViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:collectionViewLayout];
    NSLog(@"a controller is ready");
    [self setWindow:[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]];
    [_window setRootViewController:collectionViewController];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
    NSLog(@"end of app delegate");
    return YES;
}

@end
```

CollectionViewCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (strong,nonatomic) UILabel *titleLabel;

@end
```

And CollectionViewCell.m

```
#import "CollectionViewCell.h"

@implementation CollectionViewCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];NSLog(@"super was initialized");
    if (self)
    {
        _titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,self.bounds.size.height-50, self.bounds.size.width, 40.0)];
        self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [self.layer setBorderWidth:2];
        [self.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_titleLabel];
        NSLog(@"initializing a cell");
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

CollectionViewLayout.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CollectionViewLayout : UICollectionViewLayout
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *itemAttributes;
@end
```

And CollectionViewLayout.m

```
#import "CollectionViewLayout.h"


@implementation CollectionViewLayout


- (CGSize)collectionViewContentSize
{
    int kNumberOfItemsPerPage = 12;
    int numberOfItems = 24;  

    int numberOfPages = ceil((float)numberOfItems / (float)kNumberOfItemsPerPage);

    // Set the size
    float pageWidth = self.collectionView.frame.size.width;
    float pageHeight = self.collectionView.frame.size.height;
    float totalWidth = numberOfPages*pageWidth;
    CGSize contentSize = CGSizeMake(totalWidth, pageHeight);
    NSLog(@"figuring out content's size");
    return contentSize;
}

-(NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSLog(@"i am there rect attributes ");
    return [_itemAttributes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        return CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, [evaluatedObject frame]);
    }]];
}

- (void)prepareLayout
{
    //constants
    int kNumberOfItemsPerPage = 12;
    float kColumnWidth = 200;
    float kPadding = 10;
    float kRowHeight = 100;
    float kLargeCellWidth = 410;
    float kLargeCellHeight = 210;
    float kMediumCellHeight = 210;

    NSUInteger numberOfItems = [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0];

    for (int item=0;item<numberOfItems;item++)
    {
        NSLog(@"preparing layout");
        NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:0];
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:path];

        // Figure out what page this item is on
        int pageNumber = floor((float)item / (float)kNumberOfItemsPerPage);

        // Set the horizontal offset for the start of the page
        float pageWidth = self.collectionView.frame.size.width;
        float horizontalOffset = pageNumber * pageWidth;

        // Now, determine which position this cell occupies on the page.
        int indexOnPage = item % kNumberOfItemsPerPage;

        int column = 0;
        switch (indexOnPage) {
            case 0:
            case 3:
            case 5:
                column = 0;
                NSLog(@"!");
                break;
            case 1:
            case 4:
            case 6:
            case 9:
                column = 1;
                NSLog(@"@");
                break;
            case 2:
            case 7:
            case 10:
                column = 2;
                NSLog(@"#");
                break;
            case 8:
            case 11:
                column = 3;
                NSLog(@"$");
                break;
            default:
                column = 0;NSLog(@"j");
                break;
        }
            NSLog(@"preparing layout stage 2");
        int row = 0;
        switch (indexOnPage) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
            case 2:
                row = 0;
                break;
            case 3:
            case 4:
                row = 1;
                break;
            case 5:
            case 6:
            case 7:
            case 8:
                row = 2;
                break;
            case 9:
            case 10:
            case 11:
                row = 3;
                break;
            default:
                row = 0;
                break;
        }

        horizontalOffset = horizontalOffset + ((kColumnWidth + kPadding) * column);
        float verticalOffset = (kRowHeight + kPadding) * row;
            NSLog(@"preparing layout stage 3");
        // finally, determine the size of the cell.
        float width = 10.0;
        float height = 10.0;

        switch (indexOnPage) {
            case 2:
                width = kLargeCellWidth;
                height = kLargeCellHeight;
                NSLog(@"1");
                break;
            case 5:
                width = kColumnWidth;
                height = kMediumCellHeight;
                NSLog(@"3");
                break;
            default:
                width = kColumnWidth;
                height = kRowHeight;
                NSLog(@"2");
                break;
        }

        CGRect frame = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(horizontalOffset, verticalOffset, width, height));
        attributes.frame =frame;

        [_itemAttributes addObject:attributes];
            NSLog(@"preparing layout complete");
    }

}

-(BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds
{
    return NO;
}
@end
```

Finally,controller's code in
CollectionViewController.m

```
#import "CollectionViewController.h"
#import "CollectionViewCell.h"

@interface CollectionViewController ()

@end

@implementation CollectionViewController

- (id)initWithCollectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)layout
{
    self = [super initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout];
    if (self) {
        [self.collectionView registerClass:[CollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellID"];
        self.collectionView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];    }
    NSLog(@"initializing controller with a given layout");
    return self;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"returning number of items in section");
    return 24;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"filling the cell with the text"); 
    return cell;
}

@end
```

P.S I do know about about RFQuiltLayout,GooglePlusLikeLayout and other stuff like that but I want to write it on my own and understand it.Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please narrow down your problem. You have a lot code here and you haven't pinpointed where your error is occurring (like a stack trace, etc). Please help us help you. :)

Comment: @kgdesouz There is no error.This works,but in the way it is not supposed to. Basically, this code is a tut, which works,but with another layout. All the stuff about cells is brought from tut.As far as I remember cells and layout are independent and don't know anything about each other.So why it does not initialize cells? That's the question. For more clarity you can download tut from here: damir.me/implementing-uicollectionview-layout

Comment: did you ever come up with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I see a mismatching reuse Identifier.

You are registering this:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[CollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellID"];
```

Then trying to dequeue this:

```
CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

`cellID` needs to be the same as `cellIdentifier`.

Comment: Yep, my fault, thank you.Since it does not initialize cells the question is opened.